# Picture's height resizable issue

Tags: css, position, fluid-images

I have an issue when im trying to make a picture resizable, i explain:

- I have a div "overlay" that will fit the window;
- Inside this div i have another div "imgActive" that will contain some pictures centered on the window;
- Theses pictures inside has to fit the window no matter their size.

But, as you can see on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guillaumebreux/ftvovnmj/) the picture inside fit horizontaly (the width change) but when you resize the window vertically, that doesn't resize at all (the height is still the same).

```
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    height:100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
.imgActive {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.imgActive img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

What can i do to make it works? To change the height ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css directly on img. This method maintains the Aspect Ratio of the Picture

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/ykf6b5ot/

**CSS** (adjust the min and max % to suit the image size you like)

```
img {
    max-width:70%;
    max-height: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Or you can use a single class

**HTML**

```
<div class="overlay">

  <img class="image" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/471998783933251584/IF367cAS.jpeg" alt="" />

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image {
    max-width:50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/1w9s9wx7/

For the wrapper `imgActive`  you do exactly the same as the image CSS and adjust the height/width % you like. 100% is full screen

**CSS**

```
.imgActive {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/z69t00ns/

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer.
As im trying to make a small gallery plugin i thought i needed this special architecture (overlay > imgActive > img) but it doesn't seem to be as usefull as i thougt.
I will remove the imgActive and rework my plugin.

Thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: No problem. There are a few other methods like display:block but the css in the answer is mostly standard. The imgActive wrapper i can see is only useful if want another box to contain the pictures inside and moved at a particular position on the page, otherwise if the gallery will be full screen while maintainng the aspect ratio of the pictures you don't need it